# Why is Jboss named Jboss

Tags: jboss

Okay, this is definitely NOT a tech question, but I'd really love to know. 
Why is Jboss named Jboss? dug around this thing called internet and couldn't find much. 
(I get the J=java part)

Comment: J=Java, boss=The only guy who wants you to use it :)

Comment: JBoss was originally called EJBOSS, EJB OSS, Enterprise Java Beans Open Source Software. Sun then asked the project to not use EJB in its name. They, then, removed the initial E, becoming JBOSS. After that, it was "renamed" to JBoss.